Dedicated Exception handling function doesn't really except
In order to avoid using numerous try:except blocks like the one below,
I've created a dedicated function that should handle any exception,
The thing is since the data it should handle does not exist, so it fail before it reaches the handle function.
So, basically making the handle function obsolete, and making me have to use a lot of try:except blocks like before.
Furthermore, I can't use one try:except block, since not all of the parameters are needed all the time.
What is the better way to achieve this ?

Initial blocks:

     try:
         print('timestamp', event['timestamp'])
     except:
         print('No timestamp value recived')
     try:
         print('description', event['description'])
     except:
         print('No description value received')



2nd rewrite:
Code example:

def get_data(event):
    status = handle_exception(event['status'])
    print(status)

def handle_exception(parameter):
    try:
        result = parameter
    except:
        result = 'NONE'
    return result


I don't actually understand what you're trying to achieve. Specifically, your second attempt is non sequitur from the first and you're not actually handling the errors

Well, @MadPhysicist , it is literally  written in my question, that it is not handling, thus im asking a better way.

You're not calling the function anywhere I can see. please write a [mcve]

Assuming event is a dictionary or alike, you could use event.get('status') to retrieve a value or a None if the key-mapping doesn't exist.

It seems the reasonable way. no need for fancy functions and try:except,
Thanks!

Worth noting also that dict.get() can be called with a default if None isn't going to be a usable response. See this document
